# LightDM not loading in 12.04 in VirtualBox

Tags: 12.04, boot, virtualbox, display, lightdm

The boot process just stops here (below). I've tried stopping/starting lightdm but it doesn't even stop nor can I pkill it.

I've already ensured that my bios has visualization enabled and have most of the boxes checking in the settings page of VirtualBox.

I've run update, upgrade, and dist-upgrade and tried `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` (no output is displayed at all).

This is a fresh install using the alternate amd64 Ubuntu CD iso.

I noticed that it says `Stopping System V initialization compatibility` but not sure if that is good or bad.

Also, if it's relevant, I have an ATI card.

Edit: Unable to open display in any way and `sudo shutdown now` fails.

tty7: [image: tty7]

LightDM log after boot: [image: LightDM log after boot]

LightDM log after service restart: [image: LightDM log after restart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had UEFI enabled. After disabling that, I was able to boot.

Comment: I'm aware. There is a required wait time though.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue.

I have no idea what's going on, so I ended up install gdm and remove lightdm. Everything then works again.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and may be removed. Please add more details on the exact steps of how you 'removed lightdm and installed gdm'.